# Alternative to singleton?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm a Python & App Engine (and server-side!) newbie, and I'm trying to create very simple CMS. Each deployment of the application would have one -and only one -company object, instantiated from something like:

```
class Company(db.Model):
    name = db.StringPropery()
    profile = db.TextProperty()
    addr = db.TextProperty()
```

I'm trying to provide the facility to update the company profile and other details.

My first thought was to have a Company entity singleton. But having looked at (although far from totally grasped) [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046802/google-app-engine-singletons-python) I get the impression that it's difficult, and inadvisable, to do this.

So then I thought that perhaps for each deployment of the CMS I could, as a one-off, run a script (triggered by a totally obscure URL) which simply instantiates Company. From then on, I would get this instance with `theCompany = Company.all()[0]`

Is this advisable?

Then I remembered that someone in that thread suggested simply using a module. So I just created a Company.py file and stuck a few variables in it. I've tried this in the SDK and it seems to work -to my suprise, modified variable values "survived" between requests.

Forgive my ignorance but, I assume these values are only held in memory rather than on disk -unlike Datastore stuff? Is this a robust solution? (And would the module variables be in scope for all invocations of my application's scripts?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Global variables are "[app-cached](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#App_Caching)."  This means that *each* particular instance of your app will remember these variables' values between requests.  However, when an instance is shutdown these values will be lost.  Thus I do not think you really want to store these values in module-level variables (unless they are constants which do not need to be updated).

I think your original solution will work fine.  You could even create the original entity using the [remote API](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/remote_api.html) tool so that you don't need an obscure page to instantiate the one and only `Company` object.

You can also make the retrieval of the singleton `Company` entity a bit faster if you retrieve it by key.

If you will need to retrieve this entity frequently, then you can avoid round-trips to the datastore by using a caching technique.  The fastest would be to app-cache  the `Company` entity after you've retrieved it from the datastore.  To protect against the entity from becoming too out of date, you can also app-cache the time you last retrieved the entity and if that time is more than N seconds old then you could re-fetch it from the datastore.  For more details on this option and how it compares to alternatives, check out Nick Johnson's article [Storage options on App Engine](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/11/Storage-options-on-App-Engine).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are trying to provide a way for your app to be configurable on a per-application basis.

Why not use the datastore to store your company entity with a key_name?  Then you will always know how to fetch the company entity, and you'll be able edit the company without redeploying.

```
company = Company(key_name='c')
# set stuff on company....
company.put()

# later in code...
company = Company.get_by_key_name('c')
```

Use [memcache](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/usingmemcache.html) to store the details of the company and avoid repeated datastore calls.

In addition to memcache, you can use module variables to cache the values.  They are [cached](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#App_Caching), as you have seen, between requests.

Answer (score 0):

I think the approach you read about is the simplest:

- Use module variables, initialized in `None`.
- Provide accessors (get/setters) for these variables.
- When a variable is accessed, if its value is None, fetch it from the database. Otherwise, just use it.

This way, you'll have app-wide variables provided by the module (which won't be instantiated again and again), they will be shared and you won't lose them.

Comment: Since Dave mentioned that the entity might be modified, it is probably worthwhile to track when the entity was last fetched from the datastore and to re-fetch it after some period of time has passed.  This would ensure there is some upper bound on how long an app-cached copy of the entity could be out of sync with the canonical datastore value.